# Lost Unloaded Reference Edit When Importing Parent

Tags: reference, maya

I made a character rig and saved it to **file1.mb**.
Then, reference "file1.mb", animate the rig and save it to **file2.mb**. When I save the file, I unload "file1.mb" to enhance the performance of next step.
At last, I reference "file2.mb" with "Load saved reference load state". At that time, "file1,mb" is the child reference of "file2.mb", and I can read the reference edits of "file1.mb" even though it is unloaded.
BUT when I import reference of "file2.mb", the edits of "file1.mb" has gone.
I tested when "file1.mb" is loaded before importing, it keeps the edits. So, I think that this problem caused only in case of unload.

Can I find a solution for this situation? I tried "file -importReference" with some other flags, but it didn't work.

With thanks

Answer (score 0):

As soon as referenced objects are imported into your 3d scene, the reference nodes must be automatically deleted (according to Autodesk documentation). It happens in any case, using `File > Import Objects from Reference`, or using `Reference > Import` (in the Outliner), or using corresponding MEL command (`file -importReference`).

[Import file references in Maya](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-550E9963-94EA-4997-AFFF-A828EDC5F073-htm.html)